# Search comma separated value using between clause

Tags: sql-server, csv, where-clause, between

I have a table called `dayofweek`, in which data is stored in the following format, comma separated.

```
   id friday       saturday     sunday     monday   tuesday    winsday

   1  02:00,3:09   1:12,2:9     3:08,4:08  3:3,3:45  12:3,3:2   2:3,5:6,7:3,6:9
   ...
    ...
    ....
```

Now I want to search out the id, on "friday" which is available at "02:30". Put simply, I want to write a query like this:

`SELECT ID FROM dayofweek WHERE day='friday' AND time in 'commaseparatedfirstvalue' and 'comma separated second value'`

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You could do it with LIKE, or you could structure your database properly. I'd recommend the second course of action

Comment: The times aren't even formatted consistantly - surely "2:9" should be "2:09". Should "02:00" be "2:00"? How can you tell the difference between AM and PM? Also "Winsday" - really? No `Thursday` column either?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will have to write your own SQL functions that takes the time range ', for example - 02:00,3:09' and will return you the beginning of the range and the end of range , for example, let's say they are called begin_range and end_range. 
You SQL query will then look like:

```
select id from dayofweek where  '02:30' >= begin_range(friday) and '02:30' <= end_range(friday);
```